# Can I use a .env file on the client-side of my web application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using javascript and Reactjs. We have a very complicated server set up, and it would be quicker if it was possible to use the `.env` file to store our API keys and access them directly from the client.

Comment: You *want* to send your API keys to the browser?  Perhaps not a good idea from a security perspective.

Comment: no, is there a way to load .env variable on the code, so its hidden, your just refering to the env file

Comment: no, everything in the browser is potentially visible by the user.

Comment: ok cool. thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you can, but you should *not*. Especially when it comes to security concerns.

## Everything the browser reads, writes, or otherwise interacts with is also available to all users to be used as they see fit.

---

> it would be quicker if it was possible to use the .env file to store our API keys and access them directly from the client, [...] there is a way to load .env variable on the code, so its hidden, your just refering to the env file

This would effectively give those API keys to users for them to use as they see fit. There is *no* way to hide something that is sent to the browser. Nothing is stopping a user from modifying (or completely rewriting) the client-side application for themselves and displaying -- or worse, *modifying* -- any data present in there.

This is one of the reasons your server should treat every single request and response as a potential attack. Keeping that in mind, including API keys in the response is *everything* but secure, as a potential attack will pretty much effortlessly harvest your API keys.